# Packaging ES6-expressed Node files into a single Node module

Tags: node.js, grunt-browserify, grunt-babel

I have a set of interdependent Node.js modules that I have been building as ES6 modules, and I would ideally like to be able to specify a single module as an entry point and have these built (using grunt) into a single file which can be required by a Node application.

grunt-babel does not seem to be able to handle this packaging.

I know that browserify can do this for the browser, and I know browserify can include Node modules, but I haven't been able to figure out how to have browserify transform the single module entry point into a require-able Node module.

So, if my source file (and entry point), `src/hello.js` were:

```
import world from './world.js';
export default function () {console.log('Hello' + world + '!');};
```

and `src/world.js` were:

```
export default 'world';
```

I'd like it to be able to use it from a normal Node application like:

```
var hw = require('./dest/hello-world.js');
hw();
```

What would my grunt file need to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had two problems:

In my `.babelrc` file I needed:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["add-module-exports"]
}
```

...whereas in my Grunt file I needed:

```
    browserify: {
        myNode: {
            options: {
                transform: [['babelify', {sourceMaps: true}]],
                browserifyOptions: {
                    standalone: 'dummyPlaceholder'
                }
                // Depending on your needs, you may also
                //  need `node: true` here or the options
                // in the 2nd argument of the `browserify` call
                // (as I required to allow GLOBAL.window = GLOBAL
                //  injection)
                // at https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1277#issuecomment-115198436
            },
            files: {
                'dist/<%= pkg.name%>-node.js': 'src/node.js'
            }
        }
    },
```

The plugin ["add-module-exports"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) was necessary to avoid a change in Babel which necessitates calls like `var mod = require('mod').default;` instead of just `var mod = require('mod');`.

The `standalone` property is not actually used here to create a global since it is being used in a module environment (Node/CommonJS), but the property's presence is required to trigger an export.